# How to bring JOption pop up window to front?

Tags: java

I am working on my first project and it requires a JOption window to open for user input.  it works but the window is behind everything else so I have to minimize the editor to input the info.  How do I bring the window to the top?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this behaviour. The only thing I can think of is to make sure you specifify the "owner" frame when you show the option pane.

Read the JOptionPane API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Make Dialogs" for working examples.